# Nullpointer exception and error parcing JSON from flowFile attribute in NiFi

Tags: bigdata, apache-nifi

I have an "InvokeHttp" processor which on success returns JSON:

```
{"success": true, response: {}}
```

and in case of failure:

```
{"success":false,"error":{"system":"system","number":"0101","code":"INVALID_PARAMS","cause":"Invalid input parameters in request"}}
```

In case of success, I managed to process the response, but in case of failure, I can’t make a dynamic error.

At the exit from "InvokeHttp" I use the "EvaluateJSONPath" processor to cut off the excess and get JSON like this:

```
{"system":"system","number":"0101","code":"INVALID_PARAMS","cause":"Invalid input parameters in request"}
```

Then I use the "ExtractText" processor to put the FlowFile data from the text into the "error" attribute and it is successfully put there.

And finally, I need to form an error response, take the "error" attribute, and prepare the JSON using the JoltTransformJSON processor. Spec from it:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
               "errorMessage": "error"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "status": "FAIL",
      "executorType" : "nifi",
      "error" : "${errorMessage:isNull():ifElse(${error}, ${errorMessage})}"
    }
  }
]
```

and when a FlowFile with the required attribute gets into the JoltTransformJSON, I get this:
[image]

I've tried double quotes, tried escaping quotes, but that doesn't help. Please help

Comment: Your string after EvaluateJSONPath (at least above) has an extra `}` at the end, is that a typo in the question or does the data really look like that?

Comment: it is typo, thanks

Comment: How is your ExtractText configured?

Comment: Also did you extract the error message in the `errorMessage` attribute? If not you won't be able to get at the `errorMessage` field in the content, the Expression Language there only works on attributes

Comment: @mattyb thanks. ExtractText configured with default settings except flag `Enabled named group support` is `true` and add property `error` is `.*`. I solved my problem by adding another processor `UpdateOnAttribute` by putting a property in it `error` and assigning a value to it `${error:escapeJson()}` - and it worked!